# How to get the name of the cell using variables

Tags: variables, excel, range, cell, vba

I am trying to use excel VBA to enter a formula in a cell. I am doing it by, using the formula, `Cells(x,y) = "='Additional Expenses'!" + CStr(Cname)`. Where Cname will the name of the cell(i,j), So that the variable Cname has a name like: "A1" , "G5",etc. So, is there any formula I can use to change the value of Cname to the name of the cell??

Comment: Have you tried using `Range`? `Range("F10").Formula = "=""Hello World"""`

Comment: not sure what do you mean, but try this one: `Cells(x,y).Formula = "='Additional Expenses'!" & Cells(i,j).Address`

Comment: @Kami, thanks, but this is not what i was looking for. I was looking for a code to show the address for a cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cname= cells (i,j).address    'where i is a row number , j is column.

will give values like "$A$1" in a string variable type.

and later on, `Range (Cname)` , will refer to exactly the same as writing `cells(i,j)`.

and if you need to know , `i =  Range(Cname).row` , and `j = Range(Cname).Column`, to get it reversed.

Hope this helps you out.